# Is it possible to extract parts of a larger type into subtypes?

Tags: typescript, typescript3.0

It's trivial if you have 3 subtypes to put them together into one large one:

```
type Strings = {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  c: string;
  ...
};
type Numbers = {
  one: number;
  two: number;
  ...
};
type Booleans = {
  True: boolean;
  ...
};
type All = Strings & Numbers & Booleans;
```

but what if you start with the combined Type?

```
type All = {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  c: string;
  one: number; 
  two: number;
  True: boolean;
  ...
}
```

Is it possible to split `All` into the 3 sub types above based on the type of the values for each key?

I thought maybe this could work but it does not

```
type noNumbers= Exclude<All, { [key: string]: number }>;
```

[TSplayground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=15&ssc=6&pln=15&pc=15#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwM5QLxQN4FgAoKKAQwC4p0EVUBuIkgI0uqTQeKgGNWaOiAX06hIUAHIBXALZMI8TDgJcA9sgiVkMufE4lgAdxWbt8zsKKjoAIRUqANhFLJFeRlCZ37ARkoJJEOYi4NAAgvb22LD8GFAAZBKmCvFQtg5OLpyWIVDIKlKy8q4AogAe3PaSACYQADzh9gA0eFAA2gDWECB87KgAuiaF8FCCAHxZhEA)

Comment: This is neat and all, but is there some pressing reason you can't just refactor the code?

Comment: The type comes from a Library, it's big and Its a general question about the possibility of arbitrarily grouping a type.

Comment: You want [Pick](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make custom type level function in order to achieve or omitting by value type or picking by value type. Below both options:

```
// picks given values
type PickByValue<T, V, _Keys extends keyof T = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends V ? K : never
}[keyof T]> = Pick<T, _Keys>

type Numbers = PickByValue<All, number>
type Strings = PickByValue<All, string>

// omits given values
type OmitByValue<T, V, _Keys extends keyof T = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends V ? K : never
}[keyof T]> = Omit<T, _Keys>

type Bools = OmitByValue<All, number | string>
```

The key to the success is how union type treads `never`, its neutral element for `|` operator, it means it is just skipped and has no impact at the type. Consider small proove:

```
type X = 'a' | never | 'b' // evaluates to just 'a' | 'b'
```

Thanks to that we can use `never` in order to skip some keys. That is exactly visible in this part:

```
{
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends V ? K : never
}[keyof T]
```

What is happening exactly is - we create mapped type with values equal keys, but only if the value type is ok, if not we use `never`, and after that we take these values by index `[keyof T]`. Lets recap step by step what is happening:

- mapped type makes mapped type `key-> (key | never)`
- `[keyof T]` gathers all value type as union (and `never` elements are not considered)
- we now have all keys which were not skipped by `never`
- we use these keys in utility type `Pick` or `Omit`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there's an easier or better way but this works.

```
type PickOut<T, K> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends K ? P : never
}[keyof T]

type NumberKeys = PickOut<All, number>
type BooleanKeys = PickOut<All, boolean>
type StringKeys = PickOut<All, string>

type justNumbers = Pick<All, NumberKeys>
type justBooleans = Pick<All, BooleanKeys >
type justStrings = Pick<All, StringKeys >
```

[TSplayground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=21&ssc=11&pln=16&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwM5QLxQN4FgAoKKAQwC4p0EVUBuIkgI0uqTQeKgGNWaOiAX06hIUAHIBXALZMI8TDgJcA9sgiVkMufE4lgAdxWbt8zsKKjoAIRUqANhFLJFeRlCZ37ARkoJJEOYi4NAAgvb22LD8GFAAZBKmCvFQtg5OLpxEliFQAAqI3ADWAPKSwAA8ACoANFAA0gB8UcokJADaeVAoUEUQICoAZlBVALqUVZ2jUBAAHsAQyAAmmPVQAPz5UJoQAG7yQu19A8Nj2YRWibLy9f2uBcVlleH2dVrX8I05YmmOzrcge6FUrlCovOqedLOL4XXJwdioAFAx6g8FUGIw77QABWkmoUg%20yKKYIidQJOiRMMuuOovwyRJJr1SXgySKgVNyNOA8NoDLRPLQbMxhCAA)